# A way to calculate the round trip time in Java with an IP address, beside the ping command

Tags: java, delay, ping, host, roundtrip

I've implemented a way to get the RTT in Java on unix systems with the following code:

```
String command[] = {"ping", "-c4", theIPAddress};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
   //the terminal output with the ping results...
etc...
```

This works fine and I can calculate the RTT (delay) in ms with the output.
However, if a host has blocked ICMP, the ping will time-out. (Even in the Mac OS X Terminal or Windows CMD.)

Now I want to find an alternative way to somehow get the RTT/delay for an IP-address. (I don't want to install software on the host side.)
If you can't provide me a Java example, please give me other input. I can translate between many languages, and I really can use Google.

Comment: `InetAddress.isReachable` (you may need root in linux for the icmp but it has fallback on tcp). You best bet is just opening a normal TCP socket, though.

Comment: I've already tried isReachable, but fails miserably. Even worse than ping. I also though that opening a socket would be the solution, but then I need a specific port to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tracert` is short for treaceroute (and is windows command last I checked), what is just path ping - it also uses ICMP.

On linux the equivalent command is `tracepath` and on Unix-like operating systems, the `traceroute` utility by default uses **User Datagram Protocol** (UDP) datagrams with destination port numbers from 33434 to 33534. The traceroute utility usually has an `option` to specify use of **ICMP** echo request (type 8) instead, as used by the Windows `tracert` utility.

There are also traceroute implementations that use TCP packets, such as `tcptraceroute` or `layer four traceroute`.

Source: [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried tcptraceroute before but to no avail. However, with LFT I get to the target! This is the command I use `lft -E -V -m 4 ip_here`

Answer (score 1):

If the host has blocked ICMP, he doesn't want you to do this.  Try tracert instead?

Comment: ICMP is blocked by default on many routers, even ISP's. Hosts I try to ping are willing to 'answer', but are lacking knowledge of IT and Google, to enable ICMP. The software is running on a Linux distro, tracert is Windows only and also uses ICMP. But thanks for your answer!